# Using open source code in my project

Tags: open-source, licensing

I tried to find the right answer to my question but I couldn't, that's why I am here now.

Can I sell the application that I developed but contains some open source libraries? Or do I have to find people that created those libraries and ask them for permissions/pay them?

That might be a silly question but I really need to know how that  works. I am currently developing mobile app that uses someone else's library (hosted on Google Code) and I don't know if I should mention that to my client?

Thanks for any help,
marqss

Comment: That really depends on the license. In general, attribution is the minimum requirement (even with a permissive license like MIT, I think it's only fair).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the open source license of each library. You'll need to examine the licenses individually to determine what you can legally do with their libraries. For instance, the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) puts some very severe restrictions on what you can do with an application linking to a GPL library. (It's a *copyleft* license, its goal is for you to also license your app's source openly; thus it's both very open and very restrictive.) The [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html) has fewer restrictions. An MIT-style license is much freer. Some projects roll their own. Others use [CreativeCommons](http://creativecommons.org/) licenses. You get the idea.

Comment: Note, that even some GPL licensed software contains bit and pieces which are not GPL. You better skim through all source files for license comment headers. You may be surprised.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the license.

> Open source licenses are also commonly free, allowing for modification, redistribution, and commercial use without having to pay the original author. Some open source licenses only permit modification of the source code for personal use or only permit non-commercial redistribution.

See: [Open-Source License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_license), [Comparison of Free Software Licenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_licenses)

Answer (score 0):

If it's GPL, you can sell your app but you have to make your app GPL too (meaning you have to share your source).

Apache and MIT are much, much less restrictive.

Be sure to read up on what the license is for the project you are wanting to include and follow what the license tells you to do.